# Getting members of a c-type union in Swift

Tags: swift

I am using openssl for receipt validation in a Swift OS X project.  There is one line of code, to extract data from I believe a union, which I do not know how to translate into Swift:

```
ASN1_OCTET_STRING *octets = pkcs7->d.sign->contents->d.data;
```

I don't know how to deal with the "->" syntax.  What is the Swift translation of this?

Comment: Unfortunately, union fields in C structures are not accessible from Swift.

Comment: Rats!  I guess I will have to keep some C code in my project.